# Solving an exponential equation by means of factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this is my first post here. The equation I could halfway solve is this one: $4^x+4-2^x(2^{x+1}-3)=0$ How do I factor this polynomial? Is there any other way besides factoring?

Comment: Write $y=2^x$. You will end up with a quadratic in $y$, which you can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We want to solve
$$
4^x+4-2^x(2^{x+1}-3)=0.
$$
First note that $4^x = (2^2)^x = 2^{2x} = (2^x)^2$. Now substituting $y=2^x$ gives us
$$
y^2+4-y(2y-3)=0
$$
since $2^{x+1}=2\cdot 2^x = 2y$. 
Now try to solve this new equation for $y$.